# Dhis2 data set is not shown in the data entry drop down

Tags: dhis2, menu

I created a data set and assign it to organization units.  Now I notice that  the data entry drop down shows nothing when I select the organization Unit.

What is going wrong? I use Dhis version 2.31.

Comment: Try to find in the logs, do you have an error similar to: Organizational Unit not found?
And does your following page fail to load: `/dhis-web-dataentry/getDataSetAssociations.action`